# Using the WiX bootstrapper, the installer cannot work if I add a digital signature

Tags: wpf, wix, installation

I created an installer using WiX Bootstrapper (WIXWPF). It works well, but if I add a digital signature into this installer EXE file, this installer does not work. What is the reason and how do I to fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You have to sign the bundle and the engine separately. See http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/insignia.htm.